# Is there a scenario before the formation of the world?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-physics

[Energy turns into hydrogen atoms, and then the stars are born.](http://meetings.aps.org/link/BAPS.2016.SES.K1.65)، So maybe there was a scenario before the formation of the world.

Could this be a sign of a pre-designed scenario?

Has this topic (the existence of [a cosmic scenario](http://meetings.aps.org/link/BAPS.2016.SES.K1.65)) been philosophically examined so far?

Imagine I want to create a world, well, first, I need a scenario.
Could there be a scenario before the formation of the world?

Comment: Speculations based on fanciful assumptions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Are there other links you might have to the idea of "simulated reality evidence" or "scenario theory"? All I can see is an abstract in the links you provided.

Comment: You may find from the responses that your question does not quite fit with this site. The biggest issue is that an answer could not be specific and concise. If you ask a question this broad, you should qualify it by restricting it to a certain Philosophical school or Philosopher. When you are interested in views from any and all, the question should be very specific. - The "oscillating universe model" may interest you.

Comment: There is an argument that says "A physicist said this, so shouldn't philosophers of physics consider it?" To which I think the point needs to be made that presenting a paper to the APS does not necessarily mean that one's work is considered part of the domain of the science of Physics.

Answer (score 1):

> Energy turns into hydrogen atoms, and then the stars are born

That's not how stars are created. On the plus side, it's less wrong than `All stars release Big Bang's energy which is stored at Hydrogen atom` which is how the linked abstract words it.

> So maybe there was a scenario before the formation of the world

There definitely was a scenario before the formation of the world. There may even have been some notion of `before the formation of the universe` but there's no reason to believe that star formation gives us any clues to that.

> Could this be a sign of a pre-designed scenario?

Nope.

> Has this topic ... been philosophically examined so far?

Do you mean, has the idea of a `before the formation of the universe` been examined? Oh yes, endlessly. Do you mean, has the idea of a `designed universe` been examined? Yes, endlessly. Do you mean, has the idea that `star formation gives us clues to how the universe was formed`? Not that I'm aware of as it's fairly basic physics to show that the two things aren't related.

> Could there be a scenario before the formation of the world?

Again, assuming you mean universe, not world, then, yes, there could be. But this abstract isn't going to help any.

BTW Ahmad Reza Estakhr is quite well known for coming up with nonsense. Google him, he's quite prolific.

Answer (score 0):

The current position on this is that the universe was created in the single instant of the 'big bang'.
Since time itself was created in that instant there was no 'before'. At least not a before that we could understand. All mathematics is essentially useless in the conditions of the big bang since all variables are either infinite or infinitesimal. So humans currently have no tools which can analyse what may have been there before the big bang. This is unacceptable to a lot of scientists who have claimed that there may have been a universe before that, which collapsed in s big crunch, and that our universe will do the same. But this is 'turtles all the way down' stuff.